# Why are the randomly generated numbers not random?

Tags: game-maker, random

I'm trying to make a game where the damage you deal is rolled by a dice. It all works. However, it keeps on giving the same values in a row so it isn't entirely random

```
ini_open("Health.ini");
attack = ini_read_real( "Attacks", "Felix", 0);
ini_close();
global.damage=0
repeat(attack){
global.damage=irandom(6)
}


if (global.damage ==0){instance_create_depth(300, 400, 0, obj_numbers0)}
if (global.damage ==1){instance_create_depth(400, 400, 0, obj_numbers1)}
if (global.damage ==2){instance_create_depth(500, 400, 0, obj_numbers2)}
if (global.damage ==3){instance_create_depth(600, 400, 0, obj_numbers3)}
if (global.damage ==4){instance_create_depth(700, 400, 0, obj_numbers4)}
if (global.damage ==5){instance_create_depth(800, 400, 0, obj_numbers5)}
if (global.damage ==6){instance_create_depth(900, 400, 0, obj_numbers6)}
```

The attack value is 1 because it is only one dice that is used for damage for now. The software I am using is Game Maker Studio 2

Answer (score 5):

This is intended:

> NOTE: This function will return the same value every time the game is
>   run afresh due to the fact that GameMaker: Studio generates the same
>   initial random seed every time to make debugging code a far easier
>   task. To avoid this behaviour use `randomize` at the start of your game.

Check the reference [here](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/maths/real%20valued%20functions/irandom.html).

If you want to have it random every startup as well you'd have to call `randomize();` once. Check that reference [here](https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/maths/real%20valued%20functions/randomize.html).